# In which folder are kwin windows decoration themes located?

Tags: kwin

What folder are kwin windows decoration themes located in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Two places:

```
/home/user/.kde/share/apps/aurorae/themes
```

(replacing `user` with your username) and

```
/usr/share/kde4/apps/aurorae/themes
```

Answer (score 1):

The folder does not exist, if I create it and extract a theme inside 
/usr/share/kde4/apps/aurorae/themes/

I can't choose it in the settings menu
I use kwin with xfce

Comment: Is this intended to be a comment on my post?  If so, please put it as such.  Thanks!